# Programmatically configuring sonarqube webhook

Tags: sonarqube, webhooks

I'm looking for a way to programmatically configure the sonarqube webhook at a project level. The api/webhooks appears to be only for delivery. The project configuration webhooks page lists sonar.webhooks.project as a key but I've been unsuccessful getting this to work and there is no mention of it on the documentation page.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same question. When I added a webhook via the UI on project level, I get this config generated in scanner context:

```
- sonar.webhooks.project=1
- sonar.webhooks.project.1.name=Jenkins
- sonar.webhooks.project.1.url=https://myJenkins/sonarqube-webhook/
```

This works, however if I add the same config via the command line, it doesn't.

On the cli it works if I use this:

```
- sonar.webhooks.project=https://myJenkins/sonarqube-webhook/webhook/
```

In the Jenkinsfile you can use `env.JENKINS_URL` to get the Jenkins URL.

Comment: -Dsonar.webhooks.project=${env.JENKINS_URL}sonarqube-webhook/ is not working for me. I don't see anything populated in the project webhook configuration and the webhook is never called

Comment: tried adding the same key into the pom.xml files' properties sections and that didn't work either :(